# ASN1/ DER grammar for RSA key

Tags: cryptography, rsa, gmp, asn.1, der

I am looking for ASN1 grammar file for DER ASN1 encoding of RSA keys

I am looking for grammar file so that i can compile it using ASN1C compiler and subsequently write my own 'c' code using GMP to extract public key out of a given RSA key file.

It will be of grt help if some one can guide me how to generate grammar file for RSA key using the following info about DER / ASN1 format for RSA keys

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
    publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
}

RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    version           Version,
    modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
    publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
    privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
    prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
    prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
    exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
    exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
    coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
    otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL
}
```

Comment: You included the ASN.1 in your question. I'm pretty sure that's the input you should provide to an ASN.1 compiler.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , i was just missing the first and last lines , i hv posted the grammar that worked below

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions .... there was a minor header info that was to be added. following are the Grammar lines that have worked finally

```
RSAPRIVATEKEY DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e 
}
Version ::= INTEGER
RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    version           Version,
    modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
    publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
    privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
    prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
    prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
    exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
    exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1) 
    coefficient       INTEGER}  -- (inverse of q) mod p
--    otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the full grammar specification in [Appendix C of the RFC that contains the PKCS#1 RSA specification (v2.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-C).